# iTextSharp automatically shrinking images

Tags: c#, image, pdf, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to display graph images in a pdf report. Previously we've only had three graphs on one page at a 30% scale. Now I'm adding a 4th image and for some reason it doesn't automatically add it to the next page. Instead it shrinks the image to fit it onto the same page. I'm not very familiar with iTextSharp. Is there a parameter I can set it to print all images at the same size?

If it makes any difference all images are the same size, 720 wide and 380 high.

My code:

```
Image imageChart = Image.GetInstance(st);
imageChart.ScalePercent(35);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.AddElement(imageChart);
```

Report in its current state (the tiny block highlighted in the bottom left is the 4th image):
[image]

Comment: _all images are the same size, 720 wide and 380 high._ OK. But do they also have the same dpi resolution??

Comment: How would I check this?

Comment: It is a property of a Bitmap (HorizontalResolution and vres) and you can set it by calling SetResolution(xres, yres);